# What is the port number which should use to connect to cPanel MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I am trying to write a program to connect with the cPanel MySQL database.

When writing the connection string I used the below syntax.

```
string connStr = "server=localhost;user=mywebsite_root;database=online_database;port=3306;password='123456'";
```

In first place I tried this on localhost then after switch to online.

I have used the port 3306 to connect with the localserver.

But not sure which port do I need to use to connect with the cPanel database.

when I removed the port section from the above line it's not saving the data properly to the cPanel database.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This will totally depend on your web host. 3306 is the default port however some hosting companies change these.. Best to ask them

Comment: which db driver You're using?  `mysql, mysqli, pdo` ? try this: `$connStr = 'server=localhost;user=mywebsite_root;database=online_database;port=3306;password=123456';`  try one of examples from here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Answer (score 3):

It is commonly **3306**

But you can check out certainly at the header of PhpMyAdmin.

Follow these steps:
Go to your CPanel
Database section
Click on PhpMyAdmin

Now, look at [image: localhost:port]
You will see "localhost:port". That is the port you should put in `DB_PORT` at your .env file.

Just in case you don't know, the `DB_HOST` must be your Host IP.

Comment: With Cpanel, `DB_HOST` = "localhost"